# how to get the routevalues from Url in Ajax.BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ajax.beginform

how to get the routevalues from url in action method on postback of the button from Ajax.Beginform?

Should i be using below syntax ? but how to get the parameter in `routeValues` object from url?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "Author", object routeValues, new AjaxOptions()
                                     {
                                         UpdateTargetId = "resultmessage",
                                         HttpMethod = "Post",
                                         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                     }
                                   )
                   )
```

Comment: You might be misunderstanding. If you have `public AtionResult Delete(int ID)` then use `Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "Author", new { ID = SomeValue }, new AjaxOptions(), ...` or if your method accepts multiple parameters or a complex object you can pass an instance of the object in the 3rd parameter.

Comment: 'SomeValue' is in my URL. How to get from URL and store it in ID parameter?

Comment: If _SomeValue=5_ then in `public AtionResult Delete(int ID)` the value  of ID will be 5

Comment: but how to assign that SomeValue to Id in my view in the Ajax.BeginForm syntax? My URl is like http://xyz/Author/AuthorDetail/5  and here id is 5 which i want in my controller on postback.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If use `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "Author", new { ID = 5 }, ...` and which posts back to `public AtionResult Delete(int ID)` then the value of ID in the `Delete` method will be 5 (although this would not seem to make much sense for a method named `AuthorDetail` which presumably would be a GET, not a POST)

Comment: Actually AuthorDetail ( is of type GET) and it displays the details of the Author in the view and in that view i have a button which calls 'Delete' Action and that delete button is inside Ajax.BeginForm

Comment: But how do you pass value to ID in this syntax? Here you just hard coded the value but in real time that value should be from URL Right?. '@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "Author", new { ID = 5 },'

Comment: OK, I think I understand. In the `AuthorDetail` method you return a model (lets say `@model AuthorViewModel`) So in the view you would use  `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "Author", new { ID = Model.ID }, ...` assuming the `ID` property is named `ID`. But ajax calls stay on the same page so you call the `Delete` method (which deletes the author) but the author is still being displayed (a bit confusing). Why not just use a normal `@Html.BeginForm(..` which calls `Delete` and then redirects to say the `Index` page.

Comment: Thank you very much. :-) And i know it is little confusing. I am just upgrading one application and show message that particular Author is delete and i have button say' Back to List' then the user can redirect himself to Index page with the list. With time i will change the redirection. Actually at many placed i wanted this option (passing url parameter to Ajax.Begin form). Now i know. Thank you. You can create an answer so that i can mark as an answer.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass individual properties from your model you can use

```
@model AuthorViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "Author", new { ID = Model.ID }, ....
```

which posts back to

```
public ActionResult Delete(int ID) {...
```

You can also pass back a complex object (including the model itself) using

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SomeAction", "Author", Model.SomeComplexProperty, ....
```

where `Model.SomeComplexProperty` is typeof `MyOtherModel`, which posts back to

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyOtherModel model) {...
```

but this will only works if all the properties of the object are primitive values (properties that are collections or complex object are ignored)

Comment: Just a small thought again. I know i got my solution but what if i didn't have Model.Id in my model. May be it was some variable in my URL which i want to pass to my Method then how would i pass that value in `new {id=???}` in  `Ajax.BeginForm` Form?

Comment: You could use `ViewBag` so `public ActionResult AuthorDetails(int ID) { ViewBag.ID = ID; var model = ??; return View(model); }` the in the view `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "Author", new { ID = ViewBag.ID }, ....`

Comment: Thanks. I will test this option when i will have this scenario which i am sure will come. Thanks once again.